# @JoinColumn doesn't work after upgrade Hibernate version

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a strange behavior with some of my entities after migration from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5.2.17.Final and Spring from 3 to 5.0.5.RELEASE version

When I try to save an entity *HstData*, I receive en error `SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid object name 'hst_events'`.
But I have the annotation here:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "hst_events_id")
private HstEvents hstEvents;
```

The class HstEvents is very simple:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "id")
@Table(name = "hst_events")
public class HstEvents {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private byte[] data;
}
```

The full stack trace is here:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:937)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:896)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:261)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:471)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:396)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:197)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:471)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:213)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:154)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:65)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:904)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:890)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:304)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.merge(Unknown Source)
at easycare.dao.AbstractRepository.save(AbstractRepository.java:50)
at easycare.alc.dao.HstDataRepository.save(HstDataRepository.java:43)
at easycare.alc.dao.HstDataRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$54ffc850.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
at easycare.alc.dao.HstDataRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9394230f.save(<generated>)
at easycare.alc.dao.remover.HstDataRemoverTest.setupHstData(HstDataRemoverTest.java:43)
at easycare.alc.dao.remover.HstDataRemoverTest.access$000(HstDataRemoverTest.java:22)
at easycare.alc.dao.remover.HstDataRemoverTest$1.run(HstDataRemoverTest.java:37)
at easycare.dao.TransactionWrapper.runWithinTransaction(TransactionWrapper.java:20)
at easycare.dao.TransactionWrapper$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be34760c.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
at easycare.dao.TransactionWrapper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b13ea1c3.runWithinTransaction(<generated>)
at easycare.dao.NonTransactionalRepositoryTest.runWithinTransaction(NonTransactionalRepositoryTest.java:206)
at easycare.alc.dao.remover.HstDataRemoverTest.setUpAfterDbClean(HstDataRemoverTest.java:34)
at easycare.dao.NonTransactionalRepositoryTest.setUp(NonTransactionalRepositoryTest.java:192)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.execute(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$InsertSelectDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:87)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3083)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3676)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:375)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:131)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:236)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:216)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:154)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:926)
... 82 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'hst_events'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:215)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1635)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:426)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:372)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5846)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1719)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:184)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:159)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:354)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.execute(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:128)
... 99
```

First, I thought that custom naming strategy works wrong, but when I disabled it the problem occurred again.

Comment: Is that the whole error? Is there any stack trace or more information?

Comment: @Slaw added the stack trace

Comment: The error tells you doesn't exists hst_events table. Are you checked this table on your db?

Comment: @Slaw You are right! There is a table in the database, but the test is trying to connect to different DB. Thank you for the help

Comment: I think you meant to ping @JoeTaras?

Comment: @JoeTaras Please provide your answer and I'll mark it as a solution

Comment: @RuslanSheremet Dear, don't worry, the solution is very short, so it'ok as comment ;)